# Replace Special Character (ò → ⊕) when typing

Tags: text, autohotkey

Windows 10 here. I'm using the English (Canada) keyboard. Whenever I type `ALT + 8853` (alt code) I get `ò`, which I want AutoHotKey to automatically replace with ⊕.

`::a::b` works but the moment I add `ò` as part of the input, it stops functioning. How can I make AutoHotkey automatically replace `ò` with `⊕`?

```
#Requires AutoHotkey <=1.1.37.01  
:*:ò::⊕               
:*:ASC 8853::⊕      
:*:òa::⊕            
::ò::⊕              
::ASC 8853::⊕      
::òa::⊕
```

I know that I can hack together some other solution like `^k:: send {⊕}` but I don't want to manage or remember another shortcut that can conflict with another macro or program. *I am not willing to switch to windows 11.